# Oracle SQL Query - Include customer in query if they have more than 3 items across multiple orders

Tags: sql, database, oracle

EDIT: Added the query I came up with.

I'm a beginner at SQL (having it be taught as part of a database management class I am currently taking). One of my projects is to create a database revolving around customers and their orders. For this project, I have to make four tables:

```
Customer (PK = CustomerID), 
Invoice (PK = InvoiceID/ FK = CustomerID), 
Product (PK = ProductSKU), and 
Invoice_Item (PK = FK Invoice ID + FK ProductSKU).
```

I have to make a query that asks the question of "What customers have ordered more than 3 of a certain item?" The query contains the fields of the `CustomerID (C_ID), CustomerName (C_BUS), InvoiceID (I_NUM), ProductSKU (P_SKU),` and `ProductAmountOrdered (II_ORDERED)` (attribute of the `Invoice_Item` table). Also note that the `Invoice_ID` and `ProductSKU` attributes in the query are coming from the `Invoice_Item` table. Now, I answered the question with the help of some joins, but there is a catch. The customer still satisfies the criteria if they have ordered more than 3 items across multiple orders (say they order 2 in one order and 2 in another). This is the part that is tripping me up. What is the best way to go about doing this? I have looked around and haven't found anything that seems like it would solve this question. Any help wold be greatly appreciated!

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
SELECT CUSTOMER.C_ID, C_BUS, P_SKU, INVOICE.I_NUM, INVOICE_ITEM.II_ORDERED
FROM CUSTOMER, INVOICE, INVOICE_ITEM
WHERE CUSTOMER.C_ID = INVOICE.C_ID
AND INVOICE.I_NUM = INVOICE_ITEM.I_NUM
AND INVOICE_ITEM.P_SKU = 'P0548'
AND II_ORDERED > 3
ORDER BY C_BUS DESC;
```

I understand that this might not be the best syntax, but this is what I managed using my textbook as a reference.

Comment: What don't you show us what you have tried...

Comment: Just group by the Customer and Product total >= 3

Comment: Didn't have access to the query when I posted the question. Just added it in now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please modify the queries as per your naming standards.

1. query for the customers who ordered more then three of a certain item across all their invoices:

   ```
     select c.customer_id,
            c.customer_name,
            ii.product_sku,
            sum(ii.ProductAmountOrdered)
            as total_quantity_ordered
       from customer c
            inner join invoice i on c.customer_id = i.customer_id
            inner join invoice_item ii on i.invoice_id = ii.invoice_id
   group by c.customer_id,
            c.customer_name,
            ii.product_sku
     having sum(ii.ProductAmountOrdered) >= 3;
   ```
2. Query to fetch customers that ordered more then 3 of a product in a single order/invoice:

   ```
     select c.customer_id,
            c.customer_name,
            ii.invoice_id,
            ii.product_sku,
            sum(ii.ProductAmountOrdered)
            as total_quantity_ordered
       from customer c
            inner join invoice i on c.customer_id = i.customer_id
            inner join invoice_item ii on i.invoice_id = ii.invoice_id
   group by c.customer_id,
            c.customer_name,
            ii.invoice_id,
            ii.product_sku
     having sum(ii.ProductAmountOrdered) >= 3;
   ```